# Element not visible when transformed 90 deg in css3 in ie only?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I don't understand why i cant see Image 2 which is transformed 90deg with some perspective?
It works perfectly in all other browsers.
IE just rocks. IT keeps you busy for next few hours for no reasons.
Html :

```
<body>

          <div class="scene"> 
            <div class="cube">
                <div class="cube-face  cube-face-front"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img545/9813/58zj.jpg" alt="Images"> </div>
                 <div class="cube-face  cube-face-top"> <img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img818/5776/8ik6.jpg" alt="Images"> </div>

            </div>
          </div>
```

Css :

```
body {
    -webkit-transition: all .6s;
    -moz-transition: all .6s;
    -o-transition: all .6s;
    -ms-transition: all .6s;
    transition: all .6s;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.scene {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-perspective: 3000px;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

.cube {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    -o-transition: all 2s;
    -ms-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(-15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(-15deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(-15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(-15deg);
    transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(-15deg);
}

.cube-face {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=95)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=95);
    opacity: 0.95;
}

.cube-face-front {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0px);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0px);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0px);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0px);
}

.cube-face-top {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0,-150px,150px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0,-150px,150px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0,-150px,150px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0,-150px,150px);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0,-150px,150px);
}

.cube:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translate3d(0,150px,150px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translate3d(0,150px,150px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translate3d(0,150px,150px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translate3d(0,150px,150px);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translate3d(0,150px,150px);
}

img {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
```

[Here my code pen](http://codepen.io/gautam/pen/Clwki)
[My screen shot](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/557/fd3t.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply not supported by IE. See http://caniuse.com/transforms3d

You will notice that IE only has partial support, stating

> Partial support in IE10 refers to not supporting the transform-style: preserve-3d property.

I have looked for a polyfill, however it does not seems as though any currently exist. You would have to do this in jQuery if you want full support.

On a side note, I think you have a nice animation, I don't think you should worry about IE, as most people are using Chrome or FF.. too bad IE has to lag behind.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice reference.

Comment: It's still so disappointing that IE10 caught up so far, now supporting about 99% of the HTML5 specs - and then just having a few important things missing, with little chance of being able to make Javascript workarounds.

Comment: @Katana314 Yea - very disappointing. Especially since they are now developing mobile devices that have limited support too.